# Xtext: Ambiguous grammar with unary minus

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3, xtext

Could someone please explain why this is ambiguous grammar?
I have a fairly elaborate grammar and have nailed the error which I have down to this:

```
Expressions:
    AdditionOrSubtraction;

AdditionOrSubtraction:
    UnaryExpression ((PLUS | MINUS) UnaryExpression)*
;
UnaryExpression:
    MINUS Expressions
    | Atom
;
Atom returns Expression:
    INT
;
```

I looked at the java spec which gives a similar expression:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-MultiplicativeExpression

I have simplified it and showed it below:

```
MultiplicativeExpression:
    UnaryExpression 
    MultiplicativeExpression * UnaryExpression
    MultiplicativeExpression / UnaryExpression
    MultiplicativeExpression % UnaryExpression

UnaryExpression:
    + UnaryExpression 
    - UnaryExpression 
    Literal

Literal:
    IntegerLiteral
```

I get the following error message when I try to run it:
"Decision can match input such as "RULE_MINUS {RULE_MINUS, ......}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input"

Comment: Could you translate this to simple grammar like `A -> AB`, `B -> aB`, `A -> aa`. I hope you're familiar with abstract grammars, otherwise this comment won't make much sense for you. I could tell you why it's ambiguous but I don't know the syntax and structure of this language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You grammar is ambiguous since it could be parsed into two different, equally valid trees. Please consider the input `1 - 2 - 3`. It would be possible to read it in two ways (parethesis added to emphasize the ambiguous precedencies:

- 1 - ( 2 - 3 )
- (1 - 2) - 3

You would need to modify it to

```
UnaryExpression: MINUS Primary | Primary;
Primary: '(' Expressions ')' | Atom;
```

to disambiguate it.